# .NET decimal.Negate vs multiplying by -1

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, negate

Are there any differences between `decimal.Negate(myDecimal)` and `myDecimal * -1` (except maybe readability)?

Comment: If you're interested in the IL generated by both methods, write a short program that does both, and then use Red-Gate's Reflector to view the decompiled IL.

Comment: @rwmnau IL code is just an aspect of the issue, that can be discussed upon. See Jonathans comment. I am also interested in other aspects that i should consider

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect `Negate` exists because there's a unary minus operator ([`op_UnaryNegation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.op_unarynegation.aspx)), and it's good practice to have methods representing the equivalent functionality so that languages which don't support operator overloading can still achieve the same result.

So instead of comparing it with `myDecimal * -1` it may be helpful to think of it as being an alternative way of writing `-myDecimal`.

(I believe it's also optimised - given the way floating point works, negating a value is much simpler than normal multiplication; there's just a bit to flip. No need to perform any actual arithmetic.)

Answer (score 8):

If you look in the .NET source with .NET Reflector, you will see the following:
*(getting coffee until it finally opens..)*

```
public static decimal Negate(decimal d)
{
    return new decimal(d.lo, d.mid, d.hi, d.flags ^ -2147483648);
}
```

Looks like this is a fancy way to say -1 due to the way decimal internally works.

If you do *-1 it maps it to the following call:

```
FCallMultiply(ref result, yourNumber, -1M);
```

which will likely produce different IL code.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find `-myDecimal` to be more readable than either (I'm no math geek, but I pretty sure all three are equivalent), but then again, I generally prefer compact notation.

If that is out, I'd go with Negate since I like to avoid magic numbers floating around in my code, and while the `-1` as used there isn't really a magic number, it sure looks like one at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN, [`decimal.Negate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.negate.aspx):

> Returns the result of multiplying the specified Decimal value by negative one.

No practical difference then, though readability is important.

Comment: This however does not explain the implementation. Is the IL code the same?
Also, what is the purpose of having it as a separate method?

Comment: @anchandra - readability is a good reason. I did not look into the IL, but wouldn't be surprised if it was the same.

Comment: @Oded That is why I asked the question. I "guess" they are the same, but I would like a confirmation

Comment: Reflector shows the code for Negate as: `return new decimal(d.lo, d.mid, d.hi, d.flags ^ -2147483648);`.  I doubt that's the same IL generated for `myDecimal * -1` or `-myDecimal`.

Comment: Also, remember that just because the IL is the same (or different) doesn't mean it will be in the future (even in the next security patch).  Implementation being subject to change and all.

Comment: @Jonathan. Good point. I am interested in other things i should consider though. The IL code was an example of differences to have in mind between the 2 approaches